# TYPO3 Route Enhancers: List (with optional pagination and filter) + Detail on same page

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

Currently, i've got list-view and detail-view (both with optional category-parameter) on same page using two distinct route definitions as following:

```
routeEnhancers:
  RecipeListDetail:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [2]
    extension: Myext
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{category_title}', _controller: 'Recipe::list', _arguments: {'category_title': 'category'} }
      - { routePath: '/{category_title}/{recipe_title}', _controller: 'Recipe::show', _arguments: {'category_title': 'category', 'recipe_title': 'recipe'} }
    defaultController: 'Recipe::show'
    aspects:
      category_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: tx_myext_slug
      recipe_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_recipe
        routeFieldName: slug
```

Now i would like to extend this configuration with a (optional) pagination. So the configuration must be able to handle the following url formats:

```
  # List-View (optional category, optional pagination):
  /
  /category 
  /category/page-1 
  /page-1

  # Detail-View (with category):
  /category/recipe
```

In addition, another dedicated page exists for handling detail views of records when no category parameter is given. But thats not part of the problem as configuration is limited to another page.

UPDATE 2019-09-10: Tried to add 3 routes (as suggested by chris.berlin), one for each url variant. Removed to detail-view configuration for debugging:

```
  - { routePath: '/category-{category_title}/page-{page}', _controller: 'Recipe::list', _arguments: {'category_title': 'category', 'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
  - { routePath: '/category-{category_title}', _controller: 'Recipe::list', _arguments: {'category_title': 'category'} }
  - { routePath: '/page-{page}', _controller: 'Recipe::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
```

As soon as pagination gets involved, anything seems to go wrong. E.g. pagination looses category-param after first pagination link was clicked. In addition, sometimes the wrong route seems to match. Might there be any bug in using "route enhancers + pagination + additional parameters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin example works fine but the issue was it is neccessary to add „addQueryString“ to the paginate viewhelper.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add another route like this?

```
- { routePath: '/{category_title}/page/{number}'
```

Maybe like this it is possible to distinguish between the three routes list, list+paginated and detailview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **addQueryStringMethod="GET"** in f:widget.link like following

```
<f:widget.link addQueryStringMethod="GET">{page.number}</f:widget.link>
```